# 20-bit address to a register of 16-bit

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I need help with assembly; I'm just a  beginner. I'm studying NASM and x86 assembly

```
  Segment .data 
a dw 10

Segment .bss 

Segment .text 
global _main 
extern _printf 
_main: 
_b100: mov ax , 10
_b150: mov  ax , a


    
fin :

ret ;
```

what  I want to know .what will be stored in ax. because a is an address of 20bit and ax can store only 16bit . for example, if the address of a is  FFFFA what we will have in ax

Comment: Have you tried it out to see what happens? Are you familiar with the x86's segmentation?

Comment: The results should just overflow into `eax`, since ax is a 32- and 64- bit register on most machines. I agree with Thomas here- Why not try it out?

Comment: This is a 16-bit model, so a physical address is made up of a segment:register pair, typically annotated with a colon between e.g. ds:si. The absolute address is calculated as segment-value*16 + register-value, so you can address the physical address FFFFA with e.g. FFFF:A or FFF:FA.

Comment: In NASM `mov ax, a` gives you the *offset* part of label / symbol address, not the 20-bit linear address.  (That wouldn't even fit in a register.)  It's up to you to make sure NASM's idea of address locations (`org 0x100` for example in a .com executable) agrees with the current setting of DS, ES, etc.

Comment: How are you assembling this with NASM? What command line are you using to assemble. As it is, `mov ax, a` will move the 16-bit offset of `a` to AX. I ask about how you are assembling with NASM because NASM can't generate a relocatable DOS EXE by itself but it can generate a DOS COM program. DOS COM programs are loaded by the DOS loader so that CS=DS=ES=SS with an instruction pointer (IP) set to offset 0x100.

Comment: of FFFFA the A is definitely in ax. the rest of the bits are math between ax and the segment register, so you cant even say the segment register has the top 0xF in it it could be a 0xE in the upper nibble.  Please read the intel documentation, there are versions of the old 8088/86 reference manuals that do not include the new stuff so you can only see the correct information.